# Is modeling location as a categorical variable in an OLS regression considered a fixed effect model?

Tags: regression, least-squares, fixed-effects-model

My thesis advisor recommended me to model the monthly electricity consumption of households as a function of their state and multiple other regressors. In R, I turned the state variable into a `factor` and added it to the regression.

```
df$state <- df$state %>% as.factor
M1 <- lm(kwh ~ state + log(income) + household_members, data=df)
```

Is this what's known as a fixed effects model?

I'm confused because I thought fixed effects could only be applied to panel data when you subtract $y_{t+1}^i - y_t^i$ in order to get rid of them.

I am also hesitant about how to interpret each coefficient. If I'm not mistaken, the *n*th coefficient is the additional expected consumption of a household who lives in the *n*th state compared to the base level (the state when the factor level is equal to one). Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is a fixed effects model, but categorical variables can be modelled as either fixed or random effects.

There's nothing about fixed effects that is specific to panel data - any model in which you do not treat any variable as a random effect is a fixed effects model (the distinction explained in much more detail [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/what-is-the-difference-between-fixed-effect-random-effect-and-mixed-effect-mode)). In your case, I would advise modelling `state` with a random effect, though, to take advantage of the benefits of [partial pooling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/151800/121522).

Your interpretation of the coefficients is basically correct, except that you should treat the reference state (or 'base level') as having a coefficient of *zero*, not one.